# Matches ";" character in regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to detect the text like this: `E(id,x,y);`

And the code is:

```
var patt1= /\bE\[[\w]+,[\d]+,[\d]+\]\;\b/i;

document.write(patt1.test("E[id,1,2];"));
```

the result is: `false`

But when I change

```
/\bE\[[\w]+,[\d]+,[\d]+\]\;\b/i;
```

to

```
/\bE\[[\w]+,[\d]+,[\d]+\]\;/i;
```

the result is: `true`. But it allowed `E[id,1,2];moretext` too.

Comment: Have you tried yo put "$" before the final / ?

Comment: U're welcome. If you don't mind i'll post it as solution so it will be more easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! I founded.
The **\b** doesn't "detect begin and end of string." It matches a word boundary. ^ is start-of-string, $ is end-of-string.

So I change "/\bE[[\w]+,[\d]+,[\d]+]\;\b/i;" to "/^E[[\w]+,[\d]+,[\d]+]\;$/i;" for the right regular. Thank

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html is a good tool for trying regular expressions.  I don't know why you are surprised by the results, as they are correct.